# Process spawned by Daemon dies when no TTY present

Tags: c, linux, openwrt

I need to start reverse ssh tunnel from my openwrt system to my cloud machine.
The application on the openwrt system will run as daemon at startup.When it receives a specific code over the network it should spawn a process that starts a remote ssh tunnel.
There will be no logins in the system.

I am using following code to do it.

```
   int spawn_orphan(char* cmd)
{
    char command[1024]; // We could segfault if cmd is longer than 1000 bytes or so
    int pid;
    int Stat;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        perror("FORK FAILED\n");
        return pid;
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    { // CHILD
        setsid(); // Make this process the session leader of a new session
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
        {
            printf("FORK FAILED\n");
            return ( 1 );
        }
        if (pid == 0)
        { // GRANDCHILD
            sprintf(command, "ash -c '%s'", cmd);
            execl("/bin/ash", "ash", "-c", command, NULL); // Only returns on error
            perror("execl failed");
            return ( 1 );
        }
        exit(0); // SUCCESS (This child is reaped below with waitpid())
    }

    // Reap the child, leaving the grandchild to be inherited by init
    waitpid(pid, &Stat, 0);
    if ( WIFEXITED(Stat) && ( WEXITSTATUS(Stat) == 0 ))
    {
        printf("dbclient exit\n");
        return 0; // Child forked and exited successfully
    }
    else
    {
        perror("failed to spawn orphan\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

this is my calling function

```
uint8_t rdsService(uint8_t state)
{



    char buffer[1024];

    uint8_t retVal;
    if(state )
    {
        retVal = spawn_orphan("dbclient -f -K -I -T -N -R 1500:localhost:22 -p 22 username@HOSTMACHINE -i ~/ctusr/keys/X1_ID_RSA -y");


    }
    else
    {


        retVal = spawn_orphan("ash -c 'killall dbclient'");


    }

    return retVal;

}
```

If I run my parent application from console  the application is able to spawn the dbclient and I am able to do reverse ssh into the system.

The problem occurs when I run the parent application as a Daemon, in this case the application spawns the dbclient,i can see it when i do 'ps' on console, but after a few seconds the dbclient is killed.

I have already tried to run the dbclient with 'nohup'

> nohup dbclient -f -K -I -T -N -R 1500:localhost:22 -p 22
>   Username@machine-i ~/ctusr/keys/X1_ID_RSA -y &

Works fine when I run the application from console but has same error when application is run as Daemon .

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem for a month until today,
My project has only one little difference in that I use a shell script to open ash instead of a c compiled program.
I imagine you are using a proc script to run your logic after the boot procedures, if so my tip could be useful. 
In the procd script I added the home as a environment variable and that solved the problem for me.
I know that a year has passed and you could already found an alternative solution, still I hope this comment could be useful for others.
Have a good day.